# maximal value in recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I have this homework assignment:

> Let *P*<sub>*i*</sub> be the element of *arr* in index *i*. We say an index *i* is ‘well-placed’ if there exists an index *j* (*j* >= *i*) so that summing the elements in *P*<sub>*i*</sub> *P*<sub>*i*</sub>+1 … *P*<sub>*j*</sub> yields the index *i*. In other words, an index is ‘well-placed’ if a sequence of elements beginning at that index yields the index when summed.
>
> We define ‘well-placed length’ of a well-placed index to be *j*-*i*+1 – The length of the sequence that when summed shows that the index is well placed. It is possible an index is well-placed with more than a single sequence of elements. The ‘well-placed length’ in that case is the maximal length of the various sequences defining the index as ‘well-placed’.
>   The ‘maximal well-placed length’ is the maximum between the well-placement length of all well-placed indices in *arr*.
>
> If no index in the array is well-placed, the maximal well-placed length is considered to be zero.

This is the code I wrote (that does not work):

```
int longestIndexHelper(int arr[], int i, int cur, int sum, int flag)
{
    if((arr[i]==115)||(i<0))
        return 0;
    if((sum==0)&&(flag==0))
        cur= i;
    if((sum+arr[i]==cur)&&(arr[i]<=cur))
        return longestIndexHelper(arr, i+1, i, sum+arr[i], 1)+1;
    else return 0;
}

int longestIndex(int arr[], int length)
{
    int l, h;
    if(length<=0)
        return 0;
    l= longestIndexHelper(arr, length-1, 0, 0, 0);
    h= longestIndexHelper(arr, length, 0, 0, 0);
    if(h>=l)
        return longestIndex(arr, length-1);
    else
        return longestIndex(arr, length-2);
}
```

I tried to understand why it doesn't return the maximal value, I assume that the IF and ELSE need to define something else to do... I'm allowed only to use these two functions.
thank you!

Comment: what are i, cur, sum, and flag used for? use more descriptive variable names.  You might try a simpler problem first, say finding the maximum value in the array.

Comment: Where did the "115" in "arr[i] == 115" come from? Also, at the very least, you should check for i>0 *before* you use it to index 'array'.

Comment: hint: designing a recursive "helper" function that needs know whether it is being called internally or externally (your "flag") usually means you've divided up the responsibilities wrong and the helper function should be doing either more or less.

Comment: @Chris Arguin: she does check for i>=0, just in the caller, not the function itself (and recursive calls won't produce a negative i)

Comment: I'm under some stupid restristions here, so even though I would divide the responsibilities differentally, i can't. That is also why I'm forced to do stupid stuff, like shoving the '115' to the end of the array, just to know it's over.
cur= current= the index we currently compare to
flag= to know if i'm checking a match for an index, or cuntinuing the check with an existing one.

Comment: @Lady M: but you are passing the length to be examined everywhere?  you shouldn't need a sentinel value.

Comment: maybe you could describe in English how you expect your code to work, including examples of what order it examines various partitions of the array

Comment: OK, the helper function is supposed to calculate the maximal length of a "good" index (meaning- an index that stands all requirements).
The caller function is supposed to pick the bigger length everytime, and when it folds back, it's supposed to have the maximal length of all lengths recieved of indices checked, and return it to the main function.
The title of the caller function is dictated by the TAs.
If I have this array: {0,0,2,3}, then indices 3 vs. 2 will be checked. For them both the helper will return '1' to the caller (since index2=valuein that index (2), and same for 3).

Comment: Then checking for indices 2 vs. 1, here helper will return '1' for index 2, and '0' for index 1.
Now checking for index 1 vs. 0. Here the helper will return '0' for index 1, and '2' for index 0.
In the end, I want the caller to sort the maximal value of them all, and return '2' to the main functions.
Picking the maximal value (of '2' in this case) is probably my problem.

Comment: You should probably move those comments into the body of your question.  Are you sure you are allowed to do assignments?  (your l= and h=).  I'm not seeing anything in your code that would start summing at any index other than the first.

Comment: ysth- If I'm not mistaken people are supposed to help in this site, not amuse themselves on the expense of others, less experienced then they are. I'm an engineering student, and this would be the first time I'm experiencing programming (in programming 101), so- thanks for your help.

Comment: Lady M: I was trying to help.  I'm guessing you took exception to my asking about assignments; that was a serious question.  In "purely functional" programming, you wouldn't be allowed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you need to implement two "loops" via recursion; one is a loop starting at a given index and summing the values as it goes, keeping track of the maximum well placed length for that starting index.  The other is a loop trying each possible starting index.  I see that your helper function does the former. It seems that you intend the called function to do the latter, but it has no mechanism to keep track of the maximum found so far or the index to check, separate from the length of the input array.  To do that, you might want to create another helper function to recurse through all the possible starting indexes.  Though I would approach this by expanding the existing helper function to do this also, something like:

```
int _helper( int arr[], int len, int start, int cur, int sum, int max )
{
    if (start >= len) {
        /* game over, thanks for playing */
        return max;
    } else if (cur >= len) {
        /* try another starting index */
        return _helper( arr, len, start + 1, start + 1, 0, max );
    } else if ( sum + arr[cur] == start && max < cur - start + 1 ) {
        /* found a longer well placed length */
        return _helper( arr, len, start, cur + 1, sum + arr[cur], cur - start + 1 );
    } else {
        /* bzzzt.  try a longer length at this starting index */
        return _helper( arr, len, start, cur + 1, sum + arr[cur], max );
    }
}

int max_well_placed_length( int arr[], int len )
{
    return _helper( arr, len, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int arr[100];
    int len = 0;
    if (argc > 100) return 1;

    while (--argc) sscanf(*++argv, "%d", &arr[len++]); 

    printf("max well placed length: %d\n", max_well_placed_length(arr, len));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your `longestIndex` function finds the 'maximal well-placed length' for a given `length` parameter. Then it drops it (`h` and `l` aren't stored or returned anywhere, are they?), and calls itself with a decreased `length`. So the function will always return the result of either `longestIndex(arr, 0)` or `longestIndex(arr, -1)` which will be always 0.

EDIT: and the `longestIndexHelper` function can return only 0 too.